# BeautifulSoup <small> tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

I want to scrape the text between <> element. HTML code where I want to scrape "text" inside  small (which is was: 27.00). The HTML is <> class="product-views-price-old" Was: £27.00 <>
My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.petshop.co.uk/Dog"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for old_price in soup.find_all("small", class_ = "product-views-price-old"):
    print(old_price)
```

The above code gives me nothing. Even no error. How can I scrape the text between <> tags?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: The value inside the <small> tag. Which is "Was: 27£" etc

Comment: @MuhammadRehan : Check out my answer. You don't need selenium or Beautiful soup for this webpage to scrap. There is an API for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content is served dynamically, so you wont get it this way with `requests` -  Take a look at this `selenium` code.

To get rid of text and spaces you can do:

```
.get_text(strip=True).replace('Was: ','')
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://www.petshop.co.uk/Dog"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for old_price in soup.find_all("small", class_ = "product-views-price-old"):
    print(old_price.get_text(strip=True).replace('Was: ',''))

driver.quit()
```

**Output**

```
£2.20
£18.61
£27.00
£38.39
£38.39
£20.65
£1.30
£67.99
£20.65
£1.30
£54.95
£30.99
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You used selenium means this was not possible with BeautifulSoup. Am I right?

Comment: It is not `BeautifulSoup`, it is `requests` that could not fetch that dynamic content -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/55709584/14460824

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `selenium`  and `beautifulsoup` for this. There is an `API` if you go to `Network tab`. Once you get the response you need to identify the key to get the value.

[image]

> https://www.petshop.co.uk/api/items?c=3934951&commercecategoryurl=%2FDog&country=GB&currency=GBP&fieldset=search&include=facets&language=en&limit=100&n=2&offset=0&pricelevel=5&sort=custitem_bb1_qtysold%3Adesc

```
import requests
url = "https://www.petshop.co.uk/api/items?c=3934951&commercecategoryurl=%2FDog&country=GB&currency=GBP&fieldset=search&include=facets&language=en&limit=100&n=2&offset=0&pricelevel=5&sort=custitem_bb1_qtysold%3Adesc"
r = requests.get(url).json()
for item in r['items']:
       print(item['pricelevel2_formatted'])
```

**Output:**

```
£2.20
£18.61
£27.00
£5.92
£38.39
£38.39
£20.65
£1.30
£67.99
£20.65
£1.30
£54.95
£30.99
£57.95
£22.00
£46.55
£9.60
£1.99
£32.99
£30.99
£54.95
£8.21
£38.39
£57.95
£32.99
£2.65
£20.65
£10.50
£18.48
£10.50
£3.75
£2.99
£33.99
£25.00
£23.99
£1.39
£54.95
£36.99
£27.00
£49.50
£38.39
£39.59
£67.99
£32.99
£40.70
£29.69
£39.94
£31.49
£59.99
£38.39
£25.99
£67.99
£38.39
£25.99
£49.50
£39.59
£1.30
£12.90
£1.00
£44.99
£22.99
£69.99
£15.50
£2.99
£20.99
£32.99
£38.39
£15.99
£42.99
£27.12
£46.55
£52.49
£2.99
£1.99
£51.59
£2.99
£25.99
£2.99
£49.50
£18.84
£40.74
£44.99
£20.99
£39.56
£2.99
£7.09
£26.99
£18.61
£19.99
£43.99
£16.50
£12.00
£36.29
£40.40
£2.99
£35.99
£59.99
£5.50
£8.99
£57.95
```

Comment: Thank you @KunduK for the amazing answer. Will you suggest me any documentation to understand the "Network" tab xhr etc?