# Scrape a page and get html content, after javascript updates the dom on that page

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping

Is this possible? Scrape a page and get html content, after javascript updates the dom on that page? after 10 seconds or so...

The javascript on the page looks something like:

```
function renderStatisticsDiv() {
        const container = document.createElement('div');
        container.setAttribute('id', 'statisticsContainer');

        const failureCountElement = document.createElement('p');
        failureCountElement.textContent = `Failure Count: ${statistics.failureCount}`;
        const successCountElement = document.createElement('p');
        successCountElement.textContent = `Success Count: ${statistics.successCount}`;
}
```

Preferable in python, but in nodejs is fine too!

PS: I tried pyppeteer and selenium driver, but it didn't update the dom when scraping

Comment: Can you confirm the page url, is it publicly accessible?

Comment: Your JavaScript code sample creates objects, but does not add them to the DOM. No scraper will pick that up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape dynamic content from a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709463/how-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-a-website)

Comment: @ruud I left out code that adds the elements to the dom