# Web Scraping returns T&C link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

[This URL](https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/) has some CSV data files I'd like to use for analysis under the folder 'usage-stats'. However, I'm unable to scrape data from this page. When I try using the below code, I can only see the terms and conditions page instead of the links to the CSV data files:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fetch_file_list(url):

  response = requests.get(url)

  if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    links = [link.get("href") for link in soup.find_all("a")] 
  return links

fetch_file_list(<urlname>)
```

This code gives the below output:

```
['https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/terms-and-conditions/transport-data-service']
```

One additional thing I tried was using the URL including folder name. Still.. no use. I'm new to scraping.

When we're returned the T&C link are we supposed to assume scraping data from this site is impossible? If not, how else should I do it?

I need data from usage-stats folder for the time period from 2021 to 2023 which is a lot of files. I'd like to find a way to read them automatically and simply if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded dynamically via Javascript, so you have to lookup the XHR / API requests via [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) of your browser.

One will give you an XML with a list you could parse and extract the URLs of the files from.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/?list-type=2&max-keys=1500').text)
for c in soup.select('contents key'):
    if c.text.startswith('usage-stats') and c.text.endswith('.csv'):
        print('https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/'+c.text)
```

---

```
https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/usage-stats/01aJourneyDataExtract10Jan16-23Jan16.csv
https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/usage-stats/01b Journey Data Extract 24Jan16-06Feb16.csv
https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/usage-stats/01bJourneyDataExtract24Jan16-06Feb16.csv
https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/usage-stats/02aJourneyDataExtract07Fe16-20Feb2016.csv
https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/usage-stats/02bJourneyDataExtract21Feb16-05Mar2016.csv
https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/usage-stats/03JourneyDataExtract06Mar2016-31Mar2016.csv
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry to irritate but I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand how this worked. How did we get the aws link? how did we find out that data is loaded dynamically via javascript etc.. I know nothing.. Kindly explain.

Comment: There are some posts about [scraping website with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/how-can-i-scrape-a-page-with-dynamic-content-created-by-javascript-in-python) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709463/how-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-a-website  also added a link in answer to dev tools and network traffic monitoring.